# How to use the $index of trackby $index in a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my html

```
 <tr ng-show="option == 'Yearly' || option == 'Date'">
            <td>
                <label>From:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="fromdate" id="from" date-picker date-type="from" month-directive />
                {{fromdate}}
            </td>

            <td>
                <label>To:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="todate" type="text" ng-model="todate" date-picker date-type="to" month-directive />
                {{todate}}
            </td>

        </tr>
```

.....

```
<div ng-repeat=" month in months track by $index" ng-hide="fromdate == '' || todate =='' ||option != 'Yearly'">
        {{$index}}
        <input class="toBeChecked" type="checkbox" checker-directive>
        <label ng-bind="month"></label>
    </div>
```

This is my directive

```
scope.$watch('todate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            toDate = new Date(newValue);
            toDate = moment(newValue, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
            var range = moment.range(fromDate, toDate);

            range.by('months', function (moment) {

               var monthArray = moment.toArray('months');
                for (var i = 0; i <= scope.months.length; i++)
                {
                    var status = false;
                        if (i == monthArray[1]) {
                            status = true;
                        }

                    if(status)
                    {
                        $('.toBeChecked').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.toBeChecked').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                }

            });
        });

    }
```

I want to know how to get the value of $index in my directive . And how do I disable the particular checkbox if the status is true?Can anyone suggest me how to do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think $watch is a good practice for this. when does the value changes?

Comment: The value changes whenever the user tends to change the fromdate or todate

Comment: in the html....how the user sets fromdate or todate?

Comment: Using jquery datepicker

Comment: Can you post its code? you should attach ng-change and send 'this'.

Comment: I have edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a boolean variable corresponding to each month object and use that boolean variable to keep track of checkbox click state.

Use this code:-

html.ts

```
<div ng-repeat=" month in months track by month.id" ng-hide="fromdate == '' || todate =='' ||option != 'Yearly'">
        {{$index}}
        <input class="toBeChecked" type="checkbox" ng-model="month.selected" checker-directive ng-change="$ctrl.updateFunction()">
        <label ng-bind="month"></label>
</div>
```

Sample month Object is

```
{
   id : "unique_id",
   selected: "booleanValue",
   day: "day_data",
   month: "month_data"
}
```

controller.js can contain

```
function updateFunction () {
    console.log("inside update function");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-change` on :

```
 <td>
       <input type="text" ng-change="changed(this)" ng-model="fromdate" id="from" date-picker date-type="from" month-directive />
                {{fromdate}}
            </td>
```

and the same for

```
<input id="todate" type="text" ng-model="todate" ng-change="changed(this)" date-picker date-type="to" month-directive />
            {{todate}}
        </td>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.changed(self){
    console.log(self); //contians the value
}
```